# Specify levels when `mutate`-ing dataframe variables to factors

Tags: r, dplyr, r-factor, mutate

Let's say I have the following `tibble` dataframe called `data`:

```
library(tibble)

data <- tribble(
    ~"ID", ~"some factor", ~"some other factor", 
    1L, "low", "high",
    2L, "very high", "low",
    3L, "very low", "low",
    4L, "high", "very high",
    5L, "very low", "very low"
)
```

I use the `fct()` function in `forcats` to convert my two factor variables accordingly:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

data <- data %>%
        mutate(across(starts_with("some"), fct))
```

Which gives me:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
     ID `some factor` `some other factor`
  <int> <fct>         <fct>              
1     1 low           high               
2     2 very high     low                
3     3 very low      low                
4     4 high          very high          
5     5 very low      very low
```

However, when I call `fct` this way it's unclear to me how to specify the levels of this ordinal variable. The order I would like is:

```
order <- c("very low", "low", "high", "very high")
```

**How should I do this with `dplyr`'s set of functions?** The goal is to have `ggplot2` visualizations that respect this ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `across()` you can pass extra arguments along to the called function through `across`'s `...`.

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("some"), fct, levels = order))
```

This is equivalent to

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("some"), function(x) fct(x, levels = order)))
```

(This is a common paradigm in R, many functions where you are applying a function have a `...` argument for arguments that will be passed along to the applied function, see also `lapply`, `sapply`, `purrr::map`, etc.)

Comment: Thank you! BTW, when I ran the code it gave this warning "The '...' argument of 'across()' is deprecated as of dplyr 1.1.0", so I used your second version with an anonymous function instead.

Comment: Interesting! I must be a bit out-of-date :)

Answer (score 3):

```
order <- c("very low", "low", "high", "very high")

data <- data %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("some"), fct, order))
```

should do the trick